# Postgres networking with Docker containers and host LAN

Tags: postgresql, docker, dns, cidr, docker-network

I am running Postgres in a Docker container on an ARM device. I want to allow connections from both: networked containers (172.17.0.x) and also from the host's LAN network (192.168.100.x).

Is this correct?:

pg_hba.conf

```
# Docker network
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/24            md5
# Host's LAN network
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/24            md5
```

For postgres.conf, can I use CIDR masks for the `listen_addresses` field?

My networked containers' hostnames will be equal the the container names. Can I assume that the Docker DNS server will resolve all container and external-machine hostnames to the ip address and Postgres will allow these connections?

Answer (score 0):

`172.16.0.0/12`. I think your 192 should be `192.168.0.0/16` instead.